# jquery click show html and loop

Tags: html, jquery, laravel

I am doing a foreach data using laravel, then how do I loop show html
So what do I do to show html multiple times, now I can only show one time.

blade :

```
        @foreach ($portfolio_form as $portfolio_forms)

          <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn"><i class='far fa-comment'></i> 
          Comment</button>

        @endforeach

         <table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field_student">  

        </table>
```

js.

```
     $(document).ready(function(){  
      var i=1;  
     $('#add').click(function(){  
       i++;  
       $('#dynamic_field_student').html('<tr id="row'+i+'"><td>' +
       '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
        '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment_student" placeholder="" aria-label="" 
         aria-describedby="">' +
        '<div class="input-group-append">' +
            '<button class="btn btn-success" >Comment</button> '+
        '</div>'+
        '</div>'+
       '</td></tr>');  
  
  
  });  
  $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });
```

});

Comment: Please elaborate more on your issue . Not sure what you are asking .Also, as your button is under for-loop same i.e : `id="add"` is been assign to every button so only first button will work because multiple elements cannot have same ids. Instead change your `id` selector to `class` i.e : `.btn`.

Comment: I changed to class and still only show once.I want it to show multiple.

Comment: Also you have use `.html` to append new `trs` this will erase any previous data and add new to it.Change .`.html` to `.append`.

Comment: No, I mean, I foreach data to show. Then I want html to show in each foreach that I show. Sorry, I'm still a beginner.

Comment: `@foreach ($portfolio_form as $portfolio_forms)` are you sure that's right?

Comment: yeppppppppppppp

Answer (score 0):

Try following snippet, if you required like this

```js
var i = 1;
$('#add').click(function() {
  i++;
  $('#dynamic_field_student').append('<tr id="row' + i + '"><td>' +
    '<div class="input-group mb-3">' +
    '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="comment_student" placeholder="" aria-label=""     aria - describedby = "" > ' +
    '<div class="input-group-append">' +
    '<button class="btn btn-success" >Comment</button> ' +
    '<button id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove" >Remove</button> ' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</td></tr>');


});
$(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
       var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
       $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn"><i class='far fa-comment'></i> 
          Add</button>


<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field_student">

</table>
```